Enter characters from the virtual keyboard into the textarea where the cursor is located
I have a virtual keyboard and some textarea text input fields (here I have 2 input fields):
<textarea class="content" type = "text" id="content1" name = "content1" rows = "7" placeholder='abc'></textarea>
<textarea class="content" type = "text" id="content2" name = "content2" rows = "7" placeholder='abc'></textarea>
<div class="keyBoard" id="keyBoard" class="keyBoard" style="display:none">
   <table> 
    <tr>
      <td><button class="button" type="button" onclick="insertLatter('¹')" >¹</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" onclick="insertLatter('²')" >²</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" onclick="insertLatter('³')" >³</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" onclick="insertLatter('⁴')" >⁴</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" onclick="insertLatter('⁵')" >⁵</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" onclick="insertLatter('⁶')" >⁶</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" onclick="insertLatter('⁷')" >⁷</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" onclick="insertLatter('⁸')" >⁸</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" onclick="insertLatter('⁹')" >⁹</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" onclick="insertLatter('⁰')" >⁰</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" onclick="insertLatter('⁺')" >⁺</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" onclick="insertLatter('⁻')" >⁻</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" onclick="insertLatter('⁼')" >⁼</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" onclick="insertLatter('⁽')" >⁽</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" onclick="insertLatter('⁾')" >⁾</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

My goal is to be able to use this virtual keyboard to enter input values for both content1 and content2 fields. I used the following code:
function insertLetter(character) {
  const activeElement = document.activeElement; 
  if (activeElement && activeElement.tagName === 'TEXTAREA') { 
    activeElement.focus(); 
    const range = document.createRange(); 
    range.selectNode(activeElement); 
    range.collapse(true); 
    const textNode = document.createTextNode(character); 
    range.insertNode(textNode);
  }
}

But the results were not as expected.
Where did I go wrong, how should I change the code to achieve my goal?
I need your help.. Thank you.

Does this answer your question? How to insert text into the textarea at the current cursor position?

Thank you for sharing the link. However, my problem is that one keyboard can be used for multiple input fields.

I'm not certain what you're trying to achieve. You should edit your post to add more info on what you're trying to accomplish, e.g. an example of expected vs actual behavior.
